# Resetting form in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a VBA form with a variety of selection options including drop downs, text fields, checkboxes and radios.

I just wanted to know about the best way to clear all these fields with a button press. A friend of mine has tried to help by emailing me the code below but unfortunately it doesn't work, I have checked the variable names.

Any advice on how I can improve it?

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub btnReset_Click()

Unload Me
UserForm.Show

End Sub
```

Here is the other code for the userform.

```
Dim DeptCode 'Holds department code

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim c_deptCode As Range
    Dim c_deptName As Range
    Dim deptCodes As Variant
    Dim deptNames As Variant

    Dim ws_dept As Worksheet
    Set ws_dept = Worksheets("lookupDept")

    ' Assign each range to an array containing the values
    deptCodes = Choose(1, ws_dept.Range("deptCode"))
    deptNames = Choose(1, ws_dept.Range("deptName"))

    For i = 1 To ws_dept.Range("deptCode").Rows.Count
        ' Create the combined name (code + space + name)
        CombinedName = deptCodes(i, 1) & " - " & deptNames(i, 1)
        cbo_deptCode.AddItem CombinedName
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think when it hits the Unload Me line, code execution stops and that's why it's not working for you.  Here's a generic event procedure to reset all (most) of the controls on the form.

```
Private Sub cmdReset_Click()

    Dim ctl As MSForms.Control

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctl)
            Case "TextBox"
                ctl.Text = ""
            Case "CheckBox", "OptionButton", "ToggleButton"
                ctl.Value = False
            Case "ComboBox", "ListBox"
                ctl.ListIndex = -1
        End Select
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

It doesn't repopulate the ComboBoxes and ListBoxes, just clears the selection, which is what I assume you want.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is almost 2 years old BUT I was looking for an answer like this. However, I am using Access 2010 and discovered the function did not work entirely as expected:

- ctl can be Dim-ed simply as Control
- For a textbox, the ctl.Text property can only be assigned to if the control has focus (use ctl.Value instead)
- If an OptionButton is part of an OptionGroup it can not be assigned a value

So with these issues in mind, here is my rewritten function:

```
Private Sub resetForm()

    Dim ctl As Control ' Removed MSForms.

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctl)
            Case "TextBox"
                ctl.value = ""
            Case "CheckBox", "ToggleButton" ' Removed OptionButton
                ctl.value = False
            Case "OptionGroup" ' Add OptionGroup
                ctl = Null
            Case "OptionButton" ' Add OptionButton
                ' Do not reset an optionbutton if it is part of an OptionGroup
                If TypeName(ctl.Parent) <> "OptionGroup" Then ctl.value = False
            Case "ComboBox", "ListBox"
                ctl.ListIndex = -1
        End Select
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

Comment: For the ctl.ListIndex assignment, I'm getting the error that I'm using the ListIndex property incorrectly.  I had to use ctl = Null

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has this documented fairly well now for latest version of Access. It looks like some of the answers above refer to older versions. The code below is working in my app perfectly. I only included the control types I need but you can find documentation for any others in the Microsoft links below.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/textbox-controltype-property-access?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    With ctl
        Select Case .ControlType
            Case acTextBox
                .Value = ""
            Case acCheckBox
                .Value = False
            Case acComboBox
                .SetFocus
                .SelText = ""
            Case acListBox
                .Value = Null
        End Select
    End With
Next ctl
```

Note that for the combo box you have to set the focus there before setting the value.
Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/combobox-seltext-property-access

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the most recent answer - if some of your controls have defaults, you can use

`ctl.Value = ctl.DefaultValue`

Which works for me, at least for checkboxes and combo boxes.

Comment: This is good but if you want it to be an answer you should provide the full code. "the most recent answer" changes daily. If you just want to add a comment to an answer you can do that too.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
Private Sub btnReset_Click()

    Call UserForm_Initialize

End Sub
```

Comment: Your contribution would add more value to the site if you would include an explanation why your approach has advantages over the suggestions already made, years ago...

Comment: Please add more explanation. This came up under review for length and content. It maybe deleted at some point if the answer is not improved.

Comment: @CindyMeister - Well, it's a lot less code for one.  Also, the solutions above don't account for the state of controls when the form is first loaded (which may be required if one is to "reset" a form).  This should be obvious... if the solution worked.  Unfortunately, it doesn't.  Access tells me the method is not defined.

Comment: For this to work you would need to first create the initialize event. That event would then have to do something, like set the state as suggested in other answers. It is anti-pattern to call an event directly like this. Instead, you should set the state in a sub and call that by both the initialize and button.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and I solved it with the use of ESC key.

```
Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
SendKeys ("{ESC}")
End Sub
```